# mysql - Creating longer content table

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to create a big storage for page contents. Here's what i tried:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`content` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`author` MEDIUMBLOB() NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
-- 
-- Dumping data for table `pages`
--
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES (1, 'test', 'TEST_TEST_TEST');
```

And i get error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server           version for the right syntax to use near '() NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2' at line 5
```

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: On content instead of varchar(65) use bigtext and the AUTO_INCREASEMENT isn't done this way. Try making the table using HeidiSQL, it's way easier.

Comment: i want to store a big pages content, not small inputs

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, instead of varchar(65) use LONGTEXT, because varchar(65) limits your page's content to 65 characters and bigtext to 2.4 billions I think.

Comment: try this `content` text NOT NULL default ''

Comment: I'm really amazed that you have authors with such long names that you need a mediumblob for the authors, but there content will fit in 65 characters

Comment: You can not use MyIsam with ID auto increment.

Comment: But why are you using blobs anyway?

Comment: yep, sorry, i just was thinking on index and foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues I've spot:

- If you don't want to specify format details for a column, you have to omit the parenthesis. You cannot leave them empty. E.g. `INT(10)` or `INT` but not `INT()`.
- `MEDIUMBLOB` does not accept parameters: it's `MEDIUMBLOB` not `MEDIUMBLOB()`.
- A `MEDIUMBLOB` column cannot have a default value.
- You've swapped the column types for `content` and `author`.
- You're possibly abusing the `NOT NULL` constraint by applying it to all columns but then defaulting to empty strings.
- Make sure you know the difference between `''` and `NULL` anyway.
- The `TYPE` keyword was deprecated for many years and was finally removed on MySQL/5.5. Replace it with `ENGINE`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
    `content` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `author` MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Yes its the correct answer !! MEDIUMBLOB,BLOB etc can not have a default value and instead of TYPE its should be ENGINE. +1

Comment: Works well, i'll check if it works with my php code well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`content` text NOT NULL default '',
`author` MEDIUMBLOB() NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is the `blob()` statement.  Why not just use `varchar():

```
`author` varchar(1000) NOT NULL default '',
```

The insert is also expecting four columns and you are only providing three.  You should get in the habit of explicitly listing the columns in an `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO `members`(id, name, content)
    VALUES (1, 'test', 'TEST_TEST_TEST');
```

Comment: There is no problem with the blob, and it's not figuring in the question.

Comment: @xMoltenX . . . Funny.  The empty parentheses cause a problem on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9bb1).

Comment: Don't trust those sites, they're just too good to be really that good :D